# How can I format a coordinate (tuple) as a string?

Tags: python, string, return

I need to convert a coordinate ex: `C3 = (2,3)` to a string that returns `"(2 : 3)"` on this example.

```
y = str(coordenada_linha) #correspond value 3
x = str(coordenada_coluna) #correspond value 2
return str((x : y))
```

This code is totally wrong on my mind, and I don't have any idea to return on the right way.

Comment: Take a look at string's `format()` function.

Comment: `s = '(' + str(x) + ' : ' + str(y) + ')'` will do it but you should take @UlrichEckhardt advice

Comment: You could also simply `return "(" + str(x) + ":" + str(y) +  ")"`

Comment: Sorry but I have to downvote your question because it's something that you can figure out easily if you search for 5 min. I am just helping you in improving your way of working, you will need to know how to be autonomous if you keep programming.

Comment: I understand but believe me that I have been working on this simple error for a long time

Comment: @FranciscoCoito Indeed it's wrong because I haven't looked at your question well. You don't need `str` in the case you're showing, i.e. you can simply concatenate the strings...but it depends also on how your coordinates are produced...if `coordenada_linha` is indeed the number `3` and `coordenada_coluna` is indeed the number `2`, then simply concatenate the strings, as I was suggesting, or do for example as Jeff Mandel is suggesting, but that's less intuitive for beginners, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert_to_str(c):
    return "(%d : %d)"%(c[0],c[1])

>>> C3 = (2,3)
>>> print(convert_to_str(C3))
>>> (2 : 3)
```